# How to validate unique composite key of array data in laravel Validations

Tags: php, laravel, validation

Request data

```
    {
        "exam_id": 10,
        "exam_scores": [
        {
          "student_id": 1,
          "subject_id": 1,
          "marks": 50,
        },
        {
          "student_id": 1,
          "subject_id": 2,
          "marks": 70,
        },
        {
          "student_id": 1,
          "subject_id": 3,
          "marks": 80,
        }
        ],

    }
```

Where student_id and subject_id is a unique composite key, 
how to make validator for composite key with Rule Method that accepts array of data ()
I tried but it does not work as expected.

```
$validator = Validator::make(request()->all(), [
    "exam_id"=> "required|integer",
    "exam_scores"=> "required|array",
    'exam_scores.*.student_id' => [
        Rule::unique('results')->where(function ($query) {
            return $query
                ->whereStudent_idAndSubject_id(request()->get('exam_scores.*.student_id'),request()->get('exam_scores.*.subject_id'))
        })
    ],
]);
```

below request should not validate data. but it validates successfully.

```
{
        "exam_id": 10,
        "exam_scores": [
        {
          "student_id": 1,
          "subject_id": 1,
          "marks": 50,
        },
        {
          "student_id": 1,
          "subject_id": 1,
          "marks": 70,
        }
       ],

    }
```

Below request successfully validate data with single object of exam_scores that is expected.

```
    {
        "exam_id": 10,
        "exam_scores": {
            "student_id": 1,
            "subject_id": 1,
            "marks": 50,
        }
    }

$validator = Validator::make(request()->all(), [
    "exam_id"=> "required|integer",
    "exam_scores"=> "required|array",
    'exam_scores.student_id' => [
    Rule::unique('results')->where(function ($query) {
        return $query
            ->whereStudent_idAndSubject_id(request()->get('exam_scores.student_id'),request()->get('exam_scores.subject_id'))
    })
],
]);
```

Comment: are you sure about whereStudent_idAndSubject_id. As far as I know it should be whereStudentIdAndSubjectId

Comment: Yes ,field naming conventions are working perfectly.

Comment: so what you mean with "it does not work as expected"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching lots of Blogs, Tutorials & of course laravel Documentation, I got something that is solved my problem here is the blog link. that was not what I exactly wanted but it clears concept of what I have to do. 
this guy saves my day.

[Validate Dynamic request Values](https://ericlbarnes.com/2015/04/04/laravel-array-validation/)

Here is an example.

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;    
use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class OrderRequest extends Request
{

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
        ];

        foreach ($this->request->get('items') as $key => $val) {
            $rules['items.' . $key] = 'required|max:10';
        }

        return $rules;
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        $messages = [];
        foreach ($this->request->get('items') as $key => $val) {
            $messages['items.' . $key . '.max'] = 'The field labeled "Book Title ' . $key . '" must be less than :max characters.';
        }
        return $messages;
    }

}
```

> The solution were pretty much simple and easy.